# How to access ajax post checked values

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using this form to , with names and id from DB, like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row16['username']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row16['username']; ?>">
```

i am using this script to validate and to send ajax values, if  someone has any idea to receive post values, any other alternative soultion is welcome..

```
$('#tabs-2').on('click', 'input.submitadd', function(e){
    $('#form11').submit(function() {
        amIChecked = false;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                amIChecked = true;
            }
        });
        if (amIChecked) {
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"action1.php",
            data: $('#form11').serialize(), 
            cache:false,
            success: function(response){
            $('.result8').html(response);

            }
     });
     return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('please check one checkbox!');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code wires up a submit event every time input.submitadd is clicked.  Is this your intent? It doesn't actually submit the form, I don't think.

Comment: yes it submits the form.. that is my purpose too.. but getting back the values is a issue now..

Comment: @user2245360 What part of *getting back the values* is an issue for you?

Comment: from action page, guess could use up array thing

Comment: I see, so you're saying the function(response) { ... } part is not returning values?

Comment: If you click the button a second time, does it submit the form twice?

Comment: Ok. You must be reloading the form then... otherwise this happens when you click it more than once... http://jsfiddle.net/astynax777/yjUrN/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. This line:

```
if (amIChecked) {
```

Could simply be:

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
```

Without a variable being needed or using any of the logic above it. Saves a few CPU ticks!

Are you asking how to then use the data back from the server? You simply use the response object you already have in your code to examine the JSON i.e. response.SomePropertyYouJSONd.

If you have an array you could do something like this:

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    alert(response[i].PropertyName);
});​
```

In your success function.

P.S. Oh, and if you are returning JSON, you might need the following in your ajax arguments:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite to this:

```
$('#tabs-2').on('click', 'input.submitadd', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"action1.php",
            data: $('#form11').serialize(), 
            cache:false,
            success: function(response){
                $('.result8').html(response);
            }
        });          
    }
    else {
               alert('please check one checkbox!');
    }
});
```